# how to take backup of the MDS 9000 series switch configuration

Tags: cisco, storage-area-network, switch

How do i take the backup of the MDS series switch .Like after doing the Zoing and activating the zone set.How do i save my changes done so that there is no impact in the production in case of any wrong zoning??

Will appreciate if somebody can tell me the details quick!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CLI it's just "copy running-config startup-config".

Also in the Device Manager GUI tool there's an option under the Admin menu at the top called Save Configuration.

Either will let you reinstate the pre-configuration config to allow you to revert, if you want to take a copy off the MDS you can either use "copy running-config tftp/ftp/sft:location" or use the Admin/Copy Configuration dialogue in Device Manager.